# Start a JavaFX application with maven and Java 17

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-17

My System:

- Has multiple jdks (1.8, 16, 17)
- Has IntelliJ's Maven
- Is a windows 10 machine

I want to start my JavaFX app with maven. For that I use the `javafx:run` button inside of the Plugins menu.

Then I get errors about my `jdk`, being on a too-low-level (It's telling me I try to execute my Main method with my `jdk-8`), which is not true, as every single `jdk-specification` is set to `jdk-17`.

*Please don't send me any links about other posts. I have already tried those and the steps there did not work out for me.*

**This is the error I get**

- `Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`

  - Yes I already tried to change IntelliJs jdks, the JAVA_HOME variable and the run configs of maven itself
- Sometimes I also get an error from maven, telling me there is no JavaFX version 17 in the maven repository (but the maven repo of my workplace). Is there a way to change my maven-repo to the default maven website?

**This is my pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>M226a_miniproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:/Users/[user.name]/.jdks/openjdk-17/bin/javac</executable>
                    <compilerVersion>1.3</compilerVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>ch.package.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Maybe somethings wrong with the `<version>0.0.8</version>` in the second plugin?

Also: The error about the JRE not recognizing the class file does make zero sense, as even my maven is using a custom  path to my jdk-17.

Edit: Updated pom.xml

Comment: the 17-ea looks fishy - why not the current GA? Which should be fx-17 (it's emergency update, don't know its version id)

Comment: anyway, the usual strategy to resolve such config problems is to start simple (with an example that's guaranteed to work, like those from openjfx.io), no other dependencies, tweak your context until they do work for you also. The add dependencies one at a time, repeat and rinse :)

Comment: I just recently added JavaFX to the project. All the other dependencies are working just fine with maven (json-simple, junit, mockito). I already had that problem about three months ago, that I couldn't start maven, because the compiled Class file version is 61.0 and maven rather wants to use version 52.0, which is not possible, as I am using Java-17 and not Java-8.

Do you mean 17.0.0 / 17.0.1 with fx-17? As I already tried many different things and by now think my maven is broken and the pom is just "fine"

Comment: "Please don't send me any links about other posts. I have already tried those and the steps there did not work out for me." Then please list everything you have tried what did not work.

Comment: I visited many pages ranging from maven artifact stuff to JavaFX posts on Stackoverflow.
Edit: I'm currently overworking my pom.xml, as I thought that something with maven has to be wrong. (Added a second settings.xml file with mavens default values).

Comment: I had this error when the JAVA_HOME system variable was referencing an older jdk version. Maybe you want to double check that "java -version" in the win cmd prompt says 17. Good luck. Btw: `<version>0.0.8</version>` is fine.

Comment: Thank you. I already looked at that. (The JAVA_HOME variable is referencing the jdk-1.8. As I didn't want to mess up my other workspaces, I created JAVA_HOME17, which is referencing my jdk-17. I then changed something in the pom.xml to take that variable to the jdk, but that didn't work out. That's why there is a hard coded path to my jdk-17). I read that on some Stackoverflow post.

Comment: Change `<groupId>groupId</groupId>` to `<groupId>ch.package</groupId>`.

Comment: How did it go following from scratch the [JavaFX project for non-modular with Maven in Idea](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans) guide provided by openjfx.io? What error does that give on your system? Or, even simpler, the [idea new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Fixed the problem on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, but the error was the same*

The problem was, that I only had downloaded `JDK-17` into IntelliJ, but not the entire system.

Thus, I simply installed & indexed `JDK-17` by running the following commands:

One to install the JDK

```bash
> sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
```

The other to update the config to the latest JDK

```bash
> sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

The last step was to restart IntelliJ and I was good to go.